RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded en Odoo account
Mensaje de error:
Error to render compiling AST
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Template: account.report_invoice_document
Path: /t/t/t[2]/div[1]
Node: 
Error ocurrido durante la creación de la plantilla account.report_invoice_document y evalua la siguiente expresión: 

Estoy intentando imprimir una factura en Odoo14 pero me aparece lo siguiente:                                                                       Node:                                                                                                                                   ¿Podría alguien darme, por favor, alguna pista para poder resolverlo?

I am trying to print an invoice in Odoo14 but the following appears: Error to render compiling AST RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded Template: account.report_invoice_document Path: /t/t/t[2]/div[1] Node:   Please, could someone give me some clue to solve it?

Error occurred during the creation of the account.report_invoice_document template and evaluates the following expression: 
